# Why wont my method append this richTextBox

Tags: c#, winforms

Im currently trying to make an instant messaging application.

There is a client and a server. the server works perfectly but for some reason when I call a certain function to update the UI the TextBox doesn't get text added to it.

Below is an example of my code - The Update UI is called from a different form in my applicaiton:

```
public ChatWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Thread timerThread = new Thread(Main.ReceiveLoop);
        timerThread.Start();
    }

    private void txtChatLog_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void btnSendMessage_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string clientReply = txtReply.Text;
        string Message = "ClientMsg§" + clientReply;
        var time = DateTime.Now;
        txtChatLog.AppendText($"{time} client: {clientReply}");
        txtChatLog.AppendText(Environment.NewLine);
        Main main = new Main();
        main.ChatResponse(Message);
        txtReply.Text = "";

    }

    public void UpdateChatLog(string message)
    {
        var time = DateTime.Now;
        string newMessage = message.Split('$')[1];
        string messageToDisplay = $"{time} Server: {newMessage}";
        MessageBox.Show(messageToDisplay);
        txtChatLog.AppendText(messageToDisplay);
        txtChatLog.AppendText(Environment.NewLine);
    }

    private void ChatWindow_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

The client is defiantly receiving the message from the server as I checked with a messagebox.show();

Also when the send message button is pressed the rich textbox is updated. But for some reason it just wont update through the UpdateChatLog method.

Any Help would be really appreciated.

Thankyou advance!

Answer (score 0):

From code which you have pasted, you don`t call UpdateChatLog method.
Try to add UpdateChatLog(message); to btnSendMessage_Click method.

Comment: The UpdateChatLog is in a different form, it doesn't need to be in the send message button. It is defiantly being called because as mentioned the messagebox.Show is being called and displaying. Just the text box isn't changing.

Comment: @JeremyGriffin try to debug and check variable message for change and then check this line:
string newMessage = message.Split('$')[1];
may be that newMessage just couldn`t get value.

Comment: The Messagebox.show is showing that the variable is being called just before the textbox is changed so it is deffo getting the value.

Answer (score 0):

Try refreshing textbox : txtChatLog.Refresh()

Comment: Tried it with little success.